# Kivy widgets display half size

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, kivy

I am new to Kivy and have been using Richard Jones' FlappyBird model as a start.  I am currently using Kivy 1.9.2-dev0() and like using python 2.7.  I have noticed that when I launch the App, the graphics displayed are half the size.  However, the Window dimensions are displayed as the correct size (288,384), but if I track my position inside of the window it is showing it as double the size.  Also, I noticed that the x,y (0,0) position is in the bottom left as opposed to the top left?

Here is my code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.core.text import Text
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.input.motionevent import MotionEvent
from kivy.animation import Animation
import random

Config.set('graphics','resizable',0)
Window.size = (288,384)

sfx_flap = SoundLoader.load('audio/flap.wav')
sfx_score = SoundLoader.load('audio/score.wav')
sfx_die = SoundLoader.load('audio/die.wav')
sfx_music = SoundLoader.load('audio/flappymusic.wav')
sfx_level_up = SoundLoader.load('audio/level_up.wav')
sfx_lose = SoundLoader.load('audio/lose.wav')
sfx_music.loop = True

class Menu(Widget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Menu, self).__init__()
        self.add_widget(Sprite(source='images/background.png'))
        self.size = self.children[0].size
        self.add_widget(Ground(source='images/ground.png'))
        self.add_widget(Label(center=self.center, text="tap to start", 
            font_name='images/04b_19.ttf'))
        self.lives_left = Label(center_x=self.center_x, top=self.top, 
            text='x ' + str(App.lives), font_name='images/04b_19.ttf',    
            font_size=20, color=(1,1,0,1), opacity=1)
        self.add_widget(self.lives_left)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        parent = self.parent
        parent.remove_widget(self)
        parent.add_widget(Game())


class lose(Widget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(lose, self).__init__()
        self.add_widget(Sprite(source='images/background.png'))
        self.size = self.children[0].size
        self.add_widget(Ground(source='images/ground.png'))
        self.add_widget(Label(center=self.center, text="You Lose!", 
            font_name='images/04b_19.ttf', color=(1,0,0,1)))

    def on_touch_down(self, *ignore):
        pass


class Sprite(Image):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Sprite, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size = self.texture.size


class Background(Widget):
    def __init__(self, source):
        super(Background, self).__init__()
        self.image = Sprite(source=source)
        self.add_widget(self.image)
        self.size = self.image.size
#       self.image_dupe = Sprite(source=source, x=self.width)
#       self.add_widget(self.image_dupe)

    def update(self):
        self.image.x -= 2
        self.image_dupe.x -= 2

        if self.image.right <= 0:
            self.image.x = 0
            self.image_dupe.x = self.width

class Bird(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos):
        super(Bird,  self).__init__(source='atlas://images/bird_anim/wing-up', 
            pos=pos)
        self.velocity_y = 0
        self.gravity = -.3

    def update(self):
        self.velocity_y += self.gravity
        self.velocity_y = max(self.velocity_y, -10)
        self.y += self.velocity_y
        if self.velocity_y < -5:
            self.source = 'atlas://images/bird_anim/wing-up'
        elif self.velocity_y < 0:
            self.source = 'atlas://images/bird_anim/wing-mid'

    def on_touch_down(self, *ignore):
        self.velocity_y = 5.5
        self.source = 'atlas://images/bird_anim/wing-down'
        sfx_flap.play()

class Ground(Sprite):
    def update(self):
        self.x -= 2
        if self.x < -24:
            self.x += 24

class Pipe(Widget):
    def __init__(self, pos):
        super(Pipe, self).__init__(pos=pos)
        self.top_image = Sprite(source='images/pipe_top.png')
        self.top_image.pos = (self.x, self.y + 4.5 * 24)
        self.add_widget(self.top_image)
        self.bottom_image = Sprite(source='images/pipe_bottom.png')
        self.bottom_image.pos = (self.x, self.y - self.bottom_image.height)
        self.add_widget(self.bottom_image)
        self.width = self.top_image.width
        self.scored = False

    def update(self):
        self.x -= 2
        self.top_image.x = self.bottom_image.x = self.x
        if self.right < 0:
            self.parent.remove_widget(self)

class Pipes(Widget):
    add_pipe = 0
    def update(self, dt):
        for child in list(self.children):
            child.update()
        self.add_pipe -= dt
        if self.add_pipe < 0:
            y = random.randint(self.y + 50, self.height - 50 - 4.5 * 24)
            self.add_widget(Pipe(pos=(self.width, y)))
            self.add_pipe = 1.5



class Game(Widget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Game, self).__init__()
        self.background = Background(source='images/background.png')
        self.size = self.background.size
        self.add_widget(self.background)
        self.ground = Ground(source='images/ground.png')
        self.pipes = Pipes(pos=(0, self.ground.height), size=self.size)
        self.add_widget(self.pipes)
        self.add_widget(self.ground)
        self.score_label = Label(center_x=self.center_x,
            top=self.top - 30, text="0", font_name='images/04b_19.ttf')
        self.add_widget(self.score_label)
        self.over_label = Label(center=self.center, opacity=0,
            text="GameOver", font_name='images/04b_19.ttf')
        self.add_widget(self.over_label)
        self.lives_left = Label(center_x=self.center_x, top=self.top + 
            30, text='x ' + str(App.lives), 
            font_name='images/04b_19.ttf', 
            font_size=20, color=(1,1,0,1), opacity=0)
        self.add_widget(self.lives_left)
        self.bird = Bird(pos=(20, self.height / 2))
        self.add_widget(self.bird)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0/60.0)
        self.game_over = False
        self.score = 0


    def update(self, dt):
        if self.game_over:
            return

#       self.background.update()
        self.bird.update()
        self.ground.update()
        self.pipes.update(dt)
        print self.background.size


        if self.bird.collide_widget(self.ground):
            self.game_over = True

        for pipe in self.pipes.children:
            if pipe.top_image.collide_widget(self.bird):
                self.game_over = True
            elif pipe.bottom_image.collide_widget(self.bird):
                self.game_over = True
            if not pipe.scored and pipe.right < self.bird.x:
                pipe.scored = True
                self.score += 1
                self.score_label.text = str(self.score)
                sfx_score.play()
                if self.lives_left.opacity == 1:
                    self.lives_left.opacity = 0
                    self.lives_left.text = 'x ' + str(App.lives)
                if self.score % 10 == 0 and self.score != 0:
                    sfx_level_up.play()
                    App.lives += 1
                    self.lives_left.opacity = 1


        if self.game_over:
            sfx_music.stop()
            sfx_die.play()
            self.over_label.opacity = 1
            self.bind(on_touch_down=self._on_touch_down)
            App.lives -= 1
            print App.lives

    def _on_touch_down(self, *ignore):
        parent = self.parent
        parent.remove_widget(self)
        if App.lives > 0:
            sfx_music.play()
            parent.add_widget(Menu())
        else:
            parent.add_widget(lose())
            sfx_lose.play()




class FlappyBird(App):

    App.lives = 3

    def build(self):
        self.icon = 'images/flappyicon.png'
        music = sfx_music.play()
        top = Widget()
        top.add_widget(Menu())
        return Menu()
        print Window.size
        return music



if __name__ == "__main__":
    FlappyBird().run()
```

And here is a screen shot of me clicking the top right of the Window and showing its position.  The Y axis seems to be inverted and also, the window dimensions are now doubled in size?

[CONSOLE view with App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsl2U.jpg)

I was also having an issue with kivy 1.9.2 not reading the Kv Language for my Labels, that is why I added all of the args in my main.py file

any help would be appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: Zero position for UI is bottom left by default, size of widgets [100, 100]. I don't have a clue why, because that code won't run for me unless I masively edit it so... either try setting Window's size via `Config` before all (except config) imports, or edit that code to be a minimal example, please. Yet I still think it might be because of the usage of `Widget` only, which means handling all positioning and sizing on your own (and therefore a place for a lot of mistakes in the beginning) ^.^

Comment: Yeah I agree, I think the usage of the Widget itself was throwing things off.  I followed your instructions in a new project and it worked fine, so I'll go back and see where I went wrong.  Thanks!